# Gradle build failed Could not determine the dependencies of task

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I was trying to fix "Gradle build failed", but nothing worked.
Versions:
android-ndk-r23b
gradle-8.2
jdk-11.0.17
sdk from android studio
unity 2023.1.0a21

Error:

```
stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:buildReleasePreBundle'.
Could not create task ':launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.
Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
> ]
stdout[

Configure project :launcher
WARNING:The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:
android {
packagingOptions {
jniLibs {
useLegacyPackaging = true
>         }
>     }
> }

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
> ]
exit code: 1
```

I updated sdk, jdk, ndk and gradle from default that downloaded with Unity, but empty project can't build for Android

Comment: I could use an answer for this too.

Comment: @JayKoutavas you need to match all five versions: jdk, sdk, ndk, gradle and unity in their documentations and using google

Comment: @JayKoutavas also now I use unity lts 2022